# Add function during runtime to an array of animation functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, getuikit

How could I add a new Function to the function array UI.switcher.animations so I can use it during runtime?

```
Animations = {

    'none': function() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve();
        return d.promise();
    },

    'fade': function(current, next) {
        return coreAnimation.apply(this, ['@-animation-fade', current, next]);
    }
};

UI.switcher.animations = Animations;
```

The code above is part of Javascript for an switcher component of yoothemes uikit. Here is the link to the full code in github.
https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/acd4da2407070e6092459a1eab08f7020de72548/src/js/core/switcher.js